# 3 копии приложения в меню Android

Tags: android

В приложении у меня 3 активити. И при отладке в меню приложений появляется соответственно три одноимённых ярлыка запускающих ту или иную активити. Как сделать чтобы отображался только один ярлык, запускающий основную активити?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю - проблема в AndroidManifest.xml - скорее всего у вас для всез активити

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

уберите эти строки. Они у меня только для "стартовой" автивити, остальные - просто:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SecondaryActivity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Категория android.intent.category.LAUNCHER отвечает за появление данной activity в списке приложений. Оставьте данную категорию только у главного activity.